# Convert string to date and alter that date

Tags: javascript, date, variables, scope, momentjs

Good day, I am generating 3 dates from a string, I hope the output was:

```
billing date: 2020/01/11
cutoff start: 2019/11/11
cuttof end: 2019/12/10
```

but I get the following:

```
billing date: 2020/11/10
cutoff start: 2019/11/10
cuttof end: 2019/12/10
```

I would like to know how javascript works with variables or what is the problem since everything is altered

```
var month = "Jan-20"
var coverage_month_obj = moment(month, 'MMM-YY').toDate();
var billing_date = new Date(coverage_month_obj.setDate(coverage_month_obj.getDate() + 10))
var cutoff_end = new Date(billing_date.setMonth(billing_date.getMonth() - 1))
cutoff_end = new Date(billing_date.setDate(billing_date.getDate() - 1))
var cutoff_start = new Date(billing_date.setMonth(billing_date.getMonth() - 1))
```

Comment: Well you are changing the billing date....

Comment: Can you tell us the rules on how you want to calculate your 3 dates from the input `Jan-20` for example

Comment: Jan-20 I need to convert it into date format and that the day is 11 (2020/01/11)
cutoff start, are two months less from that date (2020/11/11) and cutoff end is one month less from Jan-20, but ends on day 10 (2020/12/10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know how javascript works with variables or what is the problem since everything is altered

Put simply, calling `setXXX` on a javascript date variable *updates that variable in place*. ie, it is what we would call "mutable". You might have assumed dates were immutable and did not change in place.

---

To answer on a better way to achieve your goal, I'd suggest using the [other functionality of momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) to calculate your 3 dates from the given input string.

```js
var month = "Jan-20"
var coverage_month = moment(month, 'MMM-YY');

//Jan-20 I need to convert it into date format and that the day is 11 (2020/01/11) cutoff start, are two months less from that date (2020/11/11) and cutoff end is one month less from Jan-20, but ends on day 10 (2020/12/10)

var billing_date = coverage_month.clone().add(10, 'days');
var cutoff_start = billing_date.clone().subtract(2, 'months');
var cutoff_end = billing_date.clone().subtract(1,'months').subtract(1,'day')

console.log("billing_date",billing_date);
console.log('cutoff_start',cutoff_start);
console.log('cutoff_end',cutoff_end);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```